# How to write object to a file opened by another process with async await pattern?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm busy with writing a program that writes JSON serialized objects to a JSON-file.
Now I've a problem with it. I want to write each object inside a list seperately to the JSON-file. Ofcourse in real scenario the program should add all objects to a list and hen write the list to the JSON file at once, but for now I want to do it one by one. The way I'm trying to do that introduces I/O errors and it's not clear for me why.

```
readonly BaseStore<TestObject> _store2 = new BaseStore<TestObject>("test", Settings.DatabaseBasePath);

private async void testToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Write();
}

private async Task Write()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        await _store2.Save(new TestObject
        {
            Property = "value"
        });
    }
}
```

Code of the Save method:

```
public async Task Save(T obj)
{
    var collection = _database.Load<T>(_collection);

    // do some collection changes

    await _database.Save(collection, _collection);
}
```

Above method will call the following method:

```
public async Task Save(object obj, string collectionName)
{
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", collectionName, ".json");
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None);

    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json);

    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_basePath, fileName),
        FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

Above code throws the following errors:

*Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.*

I think maybe the problem is that the Save method inside the for-loop tries to access the JSON-file while it is opened by the previous Save call, but I don't know how to solve that.

Can somebody point me into the right direction please?

Comment: Then show code of `Save` method

Comment: I added the Save method code

Comment: Put `await` before `_store2.Save`

Comment: Why are you doing `Task.Run` when you have an awaitable method inside that you can `await` on?

Comment: Also this wouldn't even compile as the `Save` method requires 2 parameters but you only pass 1.

Comment: @AlekseyL. I changed that code, but don't solves the problem.

Comment: Is this file open in any other place?

Comment: `The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.` This means that the file is in use, when you asked for *exclusive* access with `FileShare.None`. This has nothing to do with `async/await`. Try using Process Explorer to find who is using the file

Comment: @DavidG My bad. I changed the question. The Save in the loop calls the Save on the database repository first. This repository will call the 'base' Save method. I saw in my code that the first Save method contains code that retrieves the collection from the file. Maybe thats the reason??

Comment: @CornéStrijkert the error is *very* clear. The file is already open. This has nothing to do with the database or async, *unless* you are calling `Save` for the same file concurrently, eg clicking the same menu item again before the original loop had a chance to finish

Comment: You are trying to write to the file multiple times *at the same time*. You can't do that.